# SwiftUI @State var issues with popover(isPresented) func

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a fairly simple SwiftUI app (note: I'm very new to this paradigm), and I've been struggling to code that is nearly identical to what's in the Apple documentation to work.

```
@main
struct ChatMenuBarApp: App {                            
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra(currentNumber, systemImage: "\(currentNumber).circle") {
            SpeakButton(speechInput: $speechInput)
            Divider()
            Button("Quit") {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)
            }.keyboardShortcut("q")
        }
    }    
}
```

And then:

```
struct SpeakButton: View {
    @State private var isShowingPopover = false        
    var body: some View {
        Button("Audio Response") {
            self.isShowingPopover = true
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $isShowingPopover) {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("1")
    }
}
```

When I run the app and select the menu item (SpeakButton), no popover shows up.  I also notice that in the debugger, the value for self._isShowingPopover(SwiftUI.State) remains `false` even after the `self.isShowingPopover = true` line.  Feels like I'm not understanding something fundamental here.  Anyone see the issue?

The SpeakButton struct is nearly 100% identical to the example in the documentation for Popover(isPresented:) so I'm really scratching my head...

Comment: Try to wrap MenuBarExtra with WindowGroup {}

Comment: I should add that this is intended to be an always-running "menu-only" app that only shows popover windows occasionally

Comment: @Isaac that's why I don't have a WindowGroup

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that into SwiftUI for macOS, but what I found out is that the popover you are using only works in view, like this:
[image]

I assume you want a popover looking like this:

[image]

For this popover you have to write a custom AppDelegate.

```
class AppDelegate : NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusItem : NSStatusItem?
    
    var popOver = NSPopover()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let menuView = VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello World")
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        
        popOver.behavior = .transient
        popOver.animates = true
        
        popOver.contentViewController = NSViewController()
        
        popOver.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: menuView)
        
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
        if let MenuButton = statusItem?.button {
            MenuButton.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "1.circle", accessibilityDescription: nil)
            
            MenuButton.action = #selector(MenuButtonToggle)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func MenuButtonToggle(sender: AnyObject) {
        if popOver.isShown {
            popOver.performClose(sender)
        }
        else {
            if let menuButton = statusItem?.button {
                self.popOver.show(relativeTo: menuButton.bounds, of: menuButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
                popOver.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To actually use the AppDelegate use this inside your App:

```
@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
```

Maybe this video will also help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fn4YZFFVq2E

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

`MenuBarExtra` can become a popover by using `.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)`

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubarextra):

> For more complex or data rich menu bar extras, you can use the window
> style, which displays a popover-like window from the menu bar icon
> that contains standard controls. You define the layout and contents of
> those controls with the content that you provide:

```
MenuBarExtra("Utility App", systemImage: "hammer") {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(...)
    }
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
```